# How do I create a new directory through a shell script in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to create new directory `/proj` with subdirectories `bin, cgi, sbin, etc...` if `/proj` does not exist. However, instead of creating multiple subdirectories, it creates a single subdirectory named `{Changes...src}`

```
#If project directory exists, then do not create a new one.                             
if [ -d /proj ]; then
     echo "Project directory exists. New directory will not be created."

#Otherwise, create a new project directory.                                             
else
     echo "Project directory does not exist. Creating a new project directory..."
     mkdir -p proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}
fi
```

What am I missing to make the subdirectories I want?

Comment: What shell are you using? I tested `mkdir -p proj/{a,b,c}` in both `/bin/csh` and `/bin/bash`, and got the expected result (all subdirectories were created).

Comment: Your script works for me in bash (version4.2.42) for me. (I did add `#!/bin/bash` and I removed the slash in front of the `proj` on the line `if [ -d proj ];`. I don't know if that made the difference.)

Comment: If you type `printenv | grep SHELL` you should find out what shell you are running...

Comment: @mrunion - I don't think that makes a difference; it's not that "no directories" are created, but "a single one with a long name". So the problem is definitely with the `mkdir` line.

Comment: @user1854603 `echo proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}`. What is your output for this.

Comment: I have bash version 4.1.5(1)-release-(i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: & yes, there's something wrong with the `mkdir` line. It works fine naked, but just creates a single subdirectory in the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
sgeorge-mn:tmp sgeorge$ ls proj
ls: proj: No such file or directory
sgeorge-mn:tmp sgeorge$ mkdir -p proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}
sgeorge-mn:tmp sgeorge$ ls proj
Changes     Makefile    bin     cgi     doc     etc     html        lib     sbin        src
```

**FYI:**
The following means, the directory `proj` is in `/`.

```
if [ -d /proj ]; then
```

**EDIT**

***One probability I am seeing is (may not be true):***

In the comment your are saying that you are able to create directory with `mkdir -p proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}`. But after that, you are saying that "when I cd into /proj, it's still one single subdirectory". May be here is your problem.

You may already have such a directory called `/proj` .;-)

Comment: Like the "FYI" edit you made; so you are suggesting he should use `if [ -d ./proj ]`, right? It still doesn't explain why he's not getting the directories created, and you (and I) are...

Comment: @Floris, I also don't understand the mistake here. To user1854603, can you execute `echo proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}` from your shell and then can you paste its output to your question?

Comment: @Suku, this is what I get: proj/Changes proj/Makefile proj/bin proj/cgi proj/doc proj/etc proj/html proj/lib proj/sbin proj/src,

but when I `cd` into /proj, it's still one single subdirectory.

Comment: I have no issues creating the subdirectories with `mkdir -p ./proj/{Changes,Makefile,bin,cgi,doc,etc,html,lib,sbin,src}` , but doesn't work in shell script

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a [clue](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion):

"*Brace expansion is enabled via the "set -B" command and the "-B" command line option to the shell and disabled via "set +B" and "+B" on the command line.*"

Is it possible that some other script that you run (maybe automatically, or through `.bashrc`) "turns off" brace expansion? Here are some tests I did:

```
floris% /bin/bash -B
bash-3.2$ echo {1..3}
1 2 3
## ^^ brace expansion is ON

floris% /bin/bash +B
bash-3.2$ echo {1..3}
{1..3}
## ^^ brace expansion is OFF
```

Here is where it gets a little bit crazy though... If I create a simple shell script `testbrace-`:

```
#!/bin/bash -B
echo {1..3}
```

and run it from the command line like so:

```
floris% ./testbrace-
{1..3}
```

the equivalent script `testbrace+`:

```
#!/bin/bash +B
echo {1..3}
```

gives me

```
floris% ./testbrace+
{1..3}
```

In other words, the +-B flag doesn't seem to affect the way the script is run. In either case, brace expansion is DISABLED.

HOWEVER, when I specifically invoke bash from the command line with a flag, I CAN affect the outcome:

```
floris% /bin/bash +B testbrace-
{1..5}
floris% /bin/bash +B testbrace+
{1..5}
floris% /bin/bash -B testbrace-
1 2 3 4 5
floris% /bin/bash -B testbrace+
1 2 3 4 5
```

As you can see, the script will perform brace expansion IFF I call it with `/bin/bash -B scriptname` - at which point it ignores the B flag inside the script. I expect that you will get the same result if you use this method for calling your directory-creating script.

Also, make sure you change the next line to

```
if [ -d ./proj ]
```

as several people pointed out.